# chaptertitle in place of section mark in header

Tags: header-footer

I am looking to make a page that has in the header

> chapter chapter num -------------------------chaptertitle

for both odd and even pages.

Any pointers? Can someone explain how a sectionmark gets displayed in the header? And how to change the rightmark? thank you

Comment: It depends on which classes and packages you're using. Please tell us the class, the page style and packages you load for headings (`fancyhdr` or `scrpage2`?) The best would be a small compilable example.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy with [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). See code below for a basic structure.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles,raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[\chaptername\ \thechapter][][\chaptertitle]{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{}{\chaptertitle}
  \setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

As always, the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only for creating dummy text thus not part of the solution.